# How do you know what value to use for MKDirectionsApplicationSupportedModes

Tags: ios, info.plist

I didn't know you had to supply this value until I tried submitting to the app store and then I was made aware of it.

But I can't find much documentation about it. [This](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW33) appears to be the official documentation but it doesn't explain much.

How do I know if Trains, Planes, and Ferrys should be checked? My app just navigates them to an address. It's none of my business how they get there.

Comment: Seems like `MKDirectionsModeOther` would describe this situation.

Comment: The problem is always that there is no authoritative documentation. Why would `MKDirectionsModeOther` describe this situation? Is there information available that describes what that is and how, exactly, to use it? That's really the problem. I don't like relying on rumors about magic strings from would be sages on the internet. That's no way to program. Why is your thing better?